# Build a function with domain [3,5] and range [2,8] without artificial restrictions

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Build a function with domain $[3,5]$ and range $[2,8]$ without artificial restrictions.

This is a problem I recently had on a test, and I simply could not figure it out. Here are my thoughts:

I can build a function with the specified range easily by using $f(x)=3sinx+5$. I can also build a function with the specified range easily by using $g(x)=\sqrt{(5-x)(x-3)}$. So I tried to use the composition $f(g(x))=3sin(\sqrt{(5-x)(x-3)})+5$, but this changes the range. Could someone show me not only a function that meets these restrictions on the domain and range, but also your thought process on building this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the reason the composition doesn't work is that $g(x) = \sqrt{(5-x)(x-3)}$ not only has a restricted domain $[3,5]$ but a restricted range as well: we have $0 \le g(x) \le 1$ with $g(3) = g(5) = 0$ and $g(4) = 1$.

So we can get the desired range of $[2,8]$ just by scaling $g(x)$: take $h(x) = 6g(x)+2$ and we get a function undefined outside $[3,5]$ and with range $[2,8]$.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The equation for the top half of stretched circle should work perfectly:

$$y=b\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{a}-h\right)^2}+k$$

Set $h=4$, $a=1$, $k=2$ and $b=6$. Try it on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/duwgxcxx11)!

Answer (score 1):

Straight line from (3,2) to (5,8).

Comment: No, no artificial restrictions on domain and range. I'm not sure if this is the language she used on the test, but we were supposed to build a function without restricting the domain and range "artificially" as you did here.

Comment: oh okay then.  Artificial is pretty subjective.   Is the point of the problem to come up with a convoluted answer?

Comment: @Randall Most likely.